# Merge columns inside 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, orange

I have a 2D numpy array from an Orange data table.
How to merge the text from three columns into one column? All the solutions I have seen so far are about merging multiple arrays, but not about merging inside a single array.

My current attempt:

```
import numpy as np

out_data = np.hstack(in_data[:, 'ContextBefore'], in_data[:, 'Hit'], in_data[:, 'ContextAfter'])

print(out_data[:10])
```

It fails with "TypeError: hstack() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given".

Input data is a CSV file with the first rows being this:

```
"No.","Date","Genre","Bibl","URL","ContextBefore","Hit","ContextAfter"

"1","2018-01-18","Zeitung","Die Zeit, 18.01.2018, Nr. 01","http://www.zeit.de/2018/01/opernsaenger-erfolg-musikgeschaeft-karriere","Nun habe ich sie wiedergetroffen, in Leipzig, Karlsruhe, Paris und Berlin.","Es ist eine Reise rund um die Frage, wovon Erfolg abhängt.","Da war Benedikt Zeitner, Bariton, der so von sich überzeugt war, dass wir uns manchmal fragten, ob er je eine Träne vergoss."

"2","2018-01-18","Zeitung","Die Zeit, 18.01.2018, Nr. 01","http://www.zeit.de/2018/01/opernsaenger-erfolg-musikgeschaeft-karriere","Er lässt einen nicht los.","Und ich, auf dieser Reise, die auch eine Reise in meine eigene Vergangenheit ist, denke:","Es fehlt mir auch."
```

Parsing the CSV takes place in Orange with the "CSV file import" module and the Python code I'm writing resides in a "Python script" module. The last three columns with text should be merged.

Comment: Please, post a [mre]. We can't reproduce your problem. And can't really understand it from the very brief description you gave.

Comment: Is `in_data` a NumPy structured array, or a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Put the data in a list: `np.hstack([in_data[:, 'ContextBefore'], in_data[:, 'Hit'], in_data[:, 'ContextAfter']])`

Comment: if `in_data` is a pandas object, look at `stack/melt`. If numpy, consider `.T.ravel()`

Comment: From the docs: "The data is stored in 2d numpy arrays X, Y, W, metas. The arrays may be dense or sparse. All arrays have the same number of rows. If certain data is missing, the corresponding array has zero columns."

Comment: First, you haven't read the `hstack` docs carefully.  It takes a list of arrays to join.  And it does not 'merge' text.  Look at the examples.  Most of us aren't familiar with this `orange`

Comment: I was just showing my attempt, haven't seen a solution in order to join columns within one array and not for merging two arrays.

Comment: Show the 2d array (or at least a sample, a [mcve]), and show what kind of 'merge' you want.  Showing the csv doesn't help us understand what `orange` loaded, or what kind of 'merge' you want.  If you can't focus the question to `numpy`, you might need to remove the `numpy` tag, and subject line, so only `orange` users respond.  As it is, `numpy` users  are responding without much understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's the Orange data mining tool, a visual IDE, which has a Python script widget. I have no clue about how the internal data structures are looking, the docs are bad. What I have done so far: load the CSV file with the corresponding widget and attach the Python script widget.

Comment: Can be closed, my advisor allowed me to preprocess the data in Python in order to avoid messing around with Oranges weird internal data structures. But the general problem of no easy way of merging columns inside a 2D array is still there (despite I have solved my task with the ```csv``` module).